# Yii2 datapicker

Tags: yii2

В своем проекте использую Kartik `datepicker`. Возникла необходимость подключать его в JS. Вызываю так:

```
$("#test_dtpicket").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
    });
    $("#test_dtpicket").show();
```

Но `datepicker` не показывается, ошибок никаких нет?

Comment: и просто     $("#test_dtpicket").datepicker() ; тоже не работает(
Неужели так нельзя подключать скрипты

Comment: Логично, что для работы этого виджета, необходимо подключить его по инструкции. Скорее всего для его работы подтягиваются некоторые дополнительные скрипты.

Comment: Это jquery UI datapicker этот скрипт подключен. Ну и еще раз - ошибок нет ни в консоле ни в дебаге

Comment: А хтмл необходимый генерируется?

Comment: да, форма в ней поле test_dtpicket
в конце страницы в скрипте в документ-рэди добавляется указанный код

Comment: У нужного инпута точно установлен id="test_dtpicket"?

Comment: да конечно:
<input id="test_dtpicket" name="test_" type="text" />

Comment: Я хотел сказать про тот хтмл, который отображает окно с календарем. Если у нас есть инпут, js-скрипты, которые обрабатывают события, но нет самого окна, то ничего и не отобразится, а ошибок при этом может и не быть. Сделай на отдельной странице (чистой) вывод как указано в инструкции, а на второй (или потом на этой же) и сравни код ctrl+U, думаю будет разница.

Comment: Вот сделал тест http://popov.ints.net/_projects/star/site/test_dtpicker.html
тут работает, а во вьхе нет, там правда подключается
use kartik\date\DatePicker

Comment: Мне ктото ответил, на почту и отправил меня вот сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859651?noredirect=1
это не то о чем я спрашиваю. Мне таких подключений щтук 100 может понадобится, как пользователь захочет добавлять и что мне скрытых полей на бодяжить огромное кол-во, вот и хотел для селектора с меняющимся индексом (дтпикер0, везшслук1 и т.д.) которые будет добавлять пользователь и для каждого сразу подключать датапикер

Comment: Может есть какой то способ клонирования более правильный с точки зрения Yii2?